How do I stop getting "Maximum update depth exceeded" while using useEffect in react
I'm getting an error about Maximum update depth exceeded in next.js while rendering chat messages and scrolling into the last one:

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
prevent infinite loops

What might cause this error and how to fix it?
const scrollRef = useRef<ElementRef<'div'>>(null)
const [fakeLoading, setFakeLoading] = useState(messages.length === 0 ? true : false)

useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    setFakeLoading(false)
  }, 1000)

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  }
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  scrollRef?.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
}, [messages.length])

return (
  <div className="flex-1 overflow-y-auto pr-4">
    <ChatMessage 
      role="system"
      isLoading={fakeLoading}
      content={`Hello, I'm ${companion.name}, ${companion.description}`}
      src={companion.src}
    />
    {messages.map((message, key) => (
      <ChatMessage 
        key={key}
        content={message.content}
        role={message.role}
        src={companion.src}
      />
    ))}
    {isLoading && (
      <ChatMessage
        role="system"
        isLoading
        src={companion.src}
      />
    )}
    <div ref={scrollRef} />
  </div>
)


Ensure that scrollIntoView is only called when messages change.
Update the second useEffect Hook as below:
useEffect(() => {
  if (scrollRef.current) {
    scrollRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
}, [messages.length]);


How is it different from the OP's implementation?

Yes, still getting the error
